# Getting list of all orders via Shopify API

Tags: php, shopify

I can't get all **Shopify** orders via **API**, although there are orders beyond the date range that I have specified.

Neither of these URLs work for me:

https://1x877xxxxbd3ed99ae30d1eb4d71cxxx:dcfee3235061bd149ebxxxxxxxxxxxxx@store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json

https://1x877xxxxbd3ed99ae30d1eb4d71cxxx:dcfee32635061bd149ebxxxxxxxxxxxxx@store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?created_at_min=2015-08-01+3%3A00&created_at_max=2015-12-01+3%3A00

The response is as below:

> stdClass Object ( [success] => 1 [status] => OK [error] => [data] =>
>   Array ( [orders] => Array ( ) )......

However, if I just query a single order it will work

> admin/orders/2073172294.json

Answer (score 3):

I got this now.
There is no order returned with this query because it is using the default order status = open.

https://1x877xxxxbd3ed99ae30d1eb4d71cxxx:dcfee3235061bd149ebxxxxxxxxxxxxx@store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json

I just needed to set the status to "any"

https://1x877xxxxbd3ed99ae30d1eb4d71cxxx:dcfee3235061bd149ebxxxxxxxxxxxxx@store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?status=any

Comment: Did you find the answer?